# How to clear gcache pages in Percona PXC

Tags: mysql, percona-server, xtradb-cluster

I have a 4 node cluster(percona PXC) and one of the nodes have more than 150 gcache disk files each of size ~128 MB. I would like to purge or flush them so that the server user fresh gcache disk file.

I am not sure if the node restart will do it for me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

shutdown the node while maintaining quorum. so that there will be no downtime for application. manually move those all gcache files to some other location(don't delete them for safer side).Restart the server. You will get new gcache file.

Comment: kasi, thank you for the answer. do we have any workarounds similar to "purge binary logs" in mysql. We would like to keep the node up and running.

Comment: Hi Uday, ideally we will assign gcache size in Giga Bytes( for my case we assigned 8GB). ofcourse it depends on your disk size and accepted downtime of cluster node to avoid SST when node is up. whats your disk size?

Comment: i have one more question. 150 gcache disk files--whats their extension. as per this http://severalnines.com/blog/understanding-gcache-galera those pages will be deleted i guess. And gcache is a circular log file. So it will flush out the old contents in it. we do have kind of  GRA_1_14961.log files also in data directory.  each file is indication for each failed transaction.

Comment: there is no purge binary logs kind of stuff here.